# Need an example code for DMA to serial about Infineon's TriCore TC17xx

Tags: dma, infineon, tricore

I am trying to use DMA to communicate over SSC in TC1796. At this stage all I achieve is to send only 2 bytes (the first with correct content and the second with a value of zero), even though I have loaded 8 bytes to be sent.
I probably have an error in the configurations but I can't pinpoint the problem. Unfortunately MCU is obsolete and no application notes and examples are available.

Comment: Do you have any code that you've tried and could share? What have you done so far and what specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: The problem was wrong configuration - used CHCRmn.RROAT = 1 instead of CHCRmn.RROAT = 0.
Hardware-controlled send/receive is used, but rx/tx of each byte must be initiated individually by the hardware signal.
Wrongly hardware signal was used to send/receive the whole data block.